# AWS S3 access control strategies for NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to make a server in Node.js that allows users to upload files to AWS S3.

For each file uploaded there is a global unique url by default as shown below:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-website-test-psjjm/about.html
```

What are the different strategies to setup access control for these files uploaded to S3, using Node.js?

Comment: You need to take a look at this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please clarify your question? You mention "a server in Node.js", yet you give an example of a static web page in Amazon S3. It would be helpful if you can provide more detail of what you are trying to accomplish, what you have tried so far and what difficulties you are experiencing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the s3 access overview:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-control-overview.html

There are two types of access control, bucket policy and ACL. Which you use will depend on what you are trying to achieve. You'll need to go through each and decide which works best for you. These can control both account level access and external access to your bucket.

[ACL docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/S3_ACLs_UsingACLs.html)

[IAM policies docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-iam-policies.html)

Once you know what you want to achieve you can apply those policies to the bucket with a number of methods such as directly on the console, cloudformation, cli.

You can find examples [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access.html)